# IBAction not appearing in xib file (A)

Tags: xcode

I have added a normal file, and in the .h file I've added the following code:

```
-(IBAction)PushButton;
```

My problem is, the action doesn't appear in the xib file when I go into "File's Owner".

I only have the problem with my "A" files. It works perfectly fine in the "M" files.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is (A)? What is an "A" file? What is an "M" file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you have not set the class name in the xib

Comment: select the filesowner and in the inspector go to last tab.